# Kibana 5 - plotting a stacked bar plot with a different filter for each color

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I'm having a bit of truble trying to get Kibana do a certain bar chart. 
In a ridiculous reduction, it looks like this:

My data consists of documents of the following structure:

```
FULL NAME:  "Michael Jordan"
PROPERTIES: "53Y MALE 198cm" 
DEPARTMENT: Parquet

FULL NAME:  "Sasha Digiulian"
PROPERTIES: "24Y FEMALE 157cm" 
DEPARTMENT: Rock, Ice

FULL NAME:  "Ueli Steck"
PROPERTIES: "40Y MALE 187cm" 
DEPARTMENT: Ice
```

Eventually, I'd like to display a two-colored bar chart with its X axis the department, and the Y axis being a double bar with one color for the number of males for the department and another color for the number of females.

In this case there will be 3 (double) bars for

```
[Rock, Ice, Parquet]
```

with Y axis being

```
[(0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]
```

Now, for each one separately it is easy - define a filter as a query on PROPERTIES, then a (unique) count aggrigation on FULL NAME. But then again - filter is for ALL the plot, what can I do to make a different filter for each color?

Alternatively, I can try to define a scripted field, something like

```
MALE_NAME: doc['PROPERTIES'].value=~"MALE"?doc['FULL NAME'].value?""
```

and same for female. But now, scripted fields won't word on strings...

Any Ideas are greatly welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1362) is still open. But then there's a workaround [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-change-color-of-bar-graph/48790/3) using the `Split Bar` aggregation. Give it a go.